# max.in.flight.requests.per.connection property in spring boot application.prop

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I use Kafka by spring boot. I need "max.in.flight.requests.per.connection" properties. but in my ide intellij I get a message this prop can not resolve. what is equal prop

Comment: can you please post error message in more details

Comment: Also show your application properties/yml.

Comment: Don't trust Intellij. Trust the logs of the app that actually show your producer config